# Different component on the same ID ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nav

Is it possible to call in react-router on the same id two differents components?  This is my router :

```
<Route path="/Sessions" exact component={Sessions}/>
<Route path="/Sessions/:id" exact render={props => <GeekSessions{...props} /> }/>
```

I need on this schema to add an other component ( GeekDashSession ).

If you have any ideas.

Comment: It's not clear what you really want. Give us more details.

Comment: In my app, I need to redirect on the Sessions/:id two components. GeekSession who is already defined and work and an other (GeekDashSession) because my users hava different role and when one is redirect on GeekSession the other need to be redirect on the other. I don't know if it's more clear...

Comment: Got it. Do you have the "user role" on props?

Comment: Nop. I don't arrived to get the user_role from on on my user and use it....

Answer (score 0):

From what you said in the comments above, the best option is to create a `Wrapper` component that will get the `user_role` and decide which component to render. Something like this:

Wrapper.js

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user_role: null
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // get user role from api with the user id
    this.setState({ user_role: role_from_api });
  }
  render() {
  return !user_role ?
    "Loading ..."
    : user_role === "geek" ?
    <GeekSessions {...this.props} />
    :
    <GeekDashSession {...this.props} />
  }
}
```

And then you would use it like this:

`<Route path="/Sessions/:id" exact render={props => <Wrapper {...props} /> }/>`

Comment: Okay I see. I'm gonna test that.